# While downloading file in JavaFX app "This app is not responding" appears

Tags: java, linux, windows, javafx, process

I want to download a file and wait until it is downloaded so that the "Not responding" error does not appear.

```java
                     if(isNeedToReDownload){
                        launchStatus.setText(LaunchStatus.DOWNLOADING.status);
                        downloadThread = new Thread(() -> {
                            for(File file : launchDir.listFiles()){
                                file.delete();
                            }
                            launchDir.delete();
                            downloadClient();
                            downloadMods();
                        });
                        downloadThread.start();
                    }
                    if(downloadThread != null){
                        downloadThread.join();
                        downloadThread.stop();
                    }
                }
                launchStatus.setText(LaunchStatus.STARTING.status);
```

Comment: There's little point in starting a new thread and then calling `join()`; you are blocking the FX Application Thread, so it can't render anything until the background thread completes. Also, don't call `stop()` (doesn't your IDE warn you about that?).

Comment: Use a `javafx.concurrent.Task`. See the documentation for how to use one. Observe the task for when it finishes then execute the next set of instructions as appropriate. Don't block waiting for the task to finish. If you block the _JavaFX Application Thread_ then it can't do its job and the application becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create (no matter visible or not) progress bar. And on loops and other things update progress bar.

Comment: wondering what you would want to do with an invisible progressbar?

Comment: App not responding appears when UI thread is blocked more than 4 seconds. You can make progressBar.setVisible(false); and while downloading files progressBar.setProgress(1.0) and reset

Comment: if visibility matters, that's merely coindicentagl, there's something else wrong (no way to tell without a [mcve] ;) .. clean up your threading code